# How to select only rows where column contains alpha characters in spark?

Tags: regex, apache-spark

I have a spark table where somehow text is being entered into a date field.  I need to be able to select all the affect rows via regex, but am struggling to format the sql for it.

The date should look like this:

2023-02-04T07:01:02Z

so technically a 'Z' is allowed.  I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
  select * from db.table
  where  date like '%[a-zA-Y]%'
```

But that clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here; let's assume you have this dataset:

```
+------------------------+
|my_dates                |
+------------------------+
|ASD2023-02-04T07:01:02Z |
|2023-02-04T07:01:02Z    |
|2023-02-04T07:01:02ZTEST|
|TEST                    |
|20A23-B02-04CT07:01:02Z |
+------------------------+
```

If you want to tolerate some values (as in your example, where you are using `%`), you can use:

```sql
select * from table where my_dates rlike '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z'
```

which returns:

```
+------------------------+
|my_dates                |
+------------------------+
|ASD2023-02-04T07:01:02Z |
|2023-02-04T07:01:02Z    |
|2023-02-04T07:01:02ZTEST|
+------------------------+
```

If you want to do a strict check, you can do a full regex match (checking the beginning and ending of your string):

```sql
select * from table where my_dates rlike '^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z%'
```

which returns:

```
+--------------------+
|my_dates            |
+--------------------+
|2023-02-04T07:01:02Z|
+--------------------+
```

If your goal is simply to filter out the values which are not a valid time, you could even use:

```sql
select * From table where timestamp(my_dates) is not null
```

which returns:

```
+--------------------+
|my_dates            |
+--------------------+
|2023-02-04T07:01:02Z|
+--------------------+
```

Hope this helps, good luck!